# What is the exact definition of an Injective Function

Tags: functions, definition

Am I right to believe that a function is injective, if some elements of the first set are mapped to some elements of the second set?

It is also possible to 4 elements of the first set, are mapped to the same element of a second set?

Is this correct?

A simple answer is much appreciate, already confused enough :)

THANK YOU

Comment: A function is injective iff every image has __maximum one__ pre-image

Comment: if $x \neq y$ then $f(x) \neq f(y)$. Equivalently, if $f(x) = f(y) $ then $x = y$. Where $f: X \to Y$ and $x,y \in X$.

Comment: @Rymk To answer your first question, no "some elements of the first set are mapped to some elements of the second set" is not a definition of injective.  In fact, I'd ask you to think of any function whatsoever that *doesn't* meet such a vague description!

Comment: It is simply, in ordinary speech: ‘Different go to different’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An injective function (a.k.a one-to-one function) is a function for which every element of the range of the function corresponds to exactly one element of the domain.

What this means is that it never maps distinct elements of its domain to the same element of its codomain.

[image: Here is a picture to clarify it]

Comment: Suppose we have A = {a, b, c} B = {1, 2} f : A -> B given by f (a) = f (b) = f (c) = 1.

Comment: Is this a function? Why?

Comment: Well first off, it is a function, since every element in A has no more than one image in B. As to whether it is a surjective function, the answer is no, since 1, an image, has 3 distinct pre-images in the domain.

Answer (score 3):

> $f\colon X\to Y$ is injective if and only if:

> - $x\neq y\Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$, or

- If $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$

Intuition says that you can have a replica of $X$ in $Y$, it means for all $x\in X$ there are a $y\in Y$ which $f(x)=y$ and there are not other $x'$ with the same statement, $\therefore$ Y contains a copy of the set X

**Note**

> - It works for $X\to Y$, if we want something similar from $Y\to X$ it is called surjective.
> - Is possible that for some $y\in Y, \not{\exists}x\in X$ such $f(x)=y$

Answer (score 1):

Injective function is a relation satisfying $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$.

$x=y \Rightarrow f(x) = f(y)$ is the definition of partial function, so we get $f(x) = f(y) \Leftrightarrow x=y$ for injective partial function.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is **not** injective if two **distinct** elements $a,b\in X$ exist with $f(a)=f(b)$.

If that is not the case then the function is injective.