# What's the difference between $a=b \Rightarrow f(a)=f(b)$ and $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$ (injective function definition)

Tags: functions

What's the difference between $a=b \Rightarrow f(a)=f(b)$ and $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$ (injective function definition)?

Is that just a "convention" or would something go wrong?
I'd like to understand the problem/solution.

I've found the topic on stackexchange: [What is the exact definition of an Injective Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281906/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-an-injective-function)

One of the comments says: 
Injective function is a relation satisfying $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$.

$x=y \Rightarrow f(x) = f(y)$ is the definition of partial function, so we get $f(x) = f(y) 
\Leftrightarrow x=y$ for injective partial function.

Comment: If $f(x)=x^2$ on real numbers, then $a=b\implies f(a)=f(b)$ but $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=\color{red}\pm b$

Comment: I'd like to upvote you. Thank you as well! :)

Comment: It's the same as the difference between the assertions "If it's raining, then it must be cloudy" and "If it's cloudy, then it must be raining."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any function satisfies

$$a= b \implies f(a) = f(b)$$

Basically, by definition of equality sign and function!

The converse, $$f(a) = f(b) \implies a=b$$

does not hold for every function, as $f(x) = x^2$ demonstrates $(f(1) = f(-1))$.

Comment: I would say the converse does not hold for *every* function, but not that it does not hold for *any* function, because it holds for the function $f(x)=x$

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $a=b$, $f(a)$ had better equal $f(b)$, otherwise $f$ is not well-defined.

It's entirely possible that a function $f$ takes the same value at different outputs. Examples include:

- $f(x)=x^2-x$ at $x=0,1$
- $f(x)=\sin(x)$ at $x=n\pi$, $n=\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots$
- $f(x)=5$ for every $x$

The condition of injectivity prevents this from happening by requiring that if $f$ takes the same value at $a$ and $b$, then $a=b$.

Comment: Thank youuuu!!!

Answer (score 0):

The definition of function is that the same input should yield the same output (one in, one out). The definition of injective is that different inputs go to different outputs.

Comment: I don't get it, since x=/=y => f(x) =/= f(y)
this is equivalent to f(x) = f(y) => x=y

Comment: Exactly. It's an equivalent definition. You just have to be extremely careful. A function is one-to-one if different inputs yield different outputs, or equivalently, if two outputs are equal, the inputs must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

A function is a mapping between sets, such that every member of the domain (the set of inputs) has a unique output.

[image]

In this function A maps to 1, B maps to 3, C maps to 2, D maps to 3.

With this set of rules, I could give a machine any input, and it would unambiguously tell me the associated output.

A function is injective if each output has a unique input.  This function is not injective.  There are two inputs that map to 3.

If every output is associated with a unique input, then we can could reverese the process, and given a valid ouput find the associated input.

[image]

This map is injective.

We might also note that the graph of a function must pass the horizontal line test.  That is, for any horzontal line we pass through the graph of the function, the line must only intersect the graph onece.

An injective function must also pass the horizontal line test.